# Ошибка с FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

При компиляции кода выдает ошибку:

> **Error:(76, 20) error**: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class
>   FirebaseListAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   FirebaseListOptions found:
>   Notes,Class,int,DatabaseReference reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length where T is a type-variable: T extends
>   Object declared in class FirebaseListAdapter

Суть ошибка понятна, но не понятно как ее решить. Помогите в решении этой проблемы.

```
public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

FirebaseListAdapter mAdapter;

private EditText ET_new_task;
private Button Btn_new_task;

ListView ListUserTasks;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

    ListUserTasks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rv_list_tasks);
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter <String>(this, String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Tost")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String s, int position) {
            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(s);
        }
    };
    ListUserTasks.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ListUserTasks.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
            myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks").child("" + position).removeValue();
            DatabaseReference itemRef = mAdapter.getRef(position);
            itemRef.removeValue();
        }
    });

    Btn_new_task = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    ET_new_task = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_new_tasks);

    Btn_new_task.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
            myRef.child(
                    user.getUid()).child("Tasks").
                    push().
                    setValue(ET_new_task.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md - внизу есть пример создания адаптера и опций.

Comment: Вариант решения не принес результатов, возможно я не правильно понял как его реализовать но, увы. Могли бы вы помочь своим вариантом кода для моей программы ?